# Netbean 8 Variables Window, Watches Window, Breakpoints Window, Call Stack Window, Output Window don't auto hide after debug

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

Netbean 8: Variables Window, Watches Window, Breakpoints Window, Call Stack Window, Output Window don't auto hide after debug. How i can fix this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click `Window` and choose `Reset Windows` from the menu.

After doing this, the debug windows should auto-hide. I recommend taking a screenshot before doing the reset in case other customizations you made are inadvertently lost.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Minimize Window Group which is on top right corner of variable window or other windows. If you have maximized it then after debug you need to click on Minimize Window Group after debug.

Comment: Thanks! But I want windows auto minizine after i stop debug!?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out for the Output window.. if you open that view, you'll see an icon on the left-hand side which says "Ant Settings" when hovered over.  Click that, and it will open the 'Options --> Java' dialog.

In that dialog, select the 'Always Show Output' option.  Now anytime you build your project (etc) that Output view will pop up, and when you click back in the Editor it will auto-hide.